# Visual Basic combobox with mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

I have this VB code that populates a combobox with data from a MySQL table

```
Dim sStmt As String = "SELECT sequence, name FROM product_categories"
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(sStmt, sqlcon)

            Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dt As New DataTable("product_categories")
            da.Fill(dt)

            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                category.DataSource = dt
                category.DisplayMember = "name" 'What is displayed
                category.ValueMember = "sequence" 'The ID of the row
            End If
```

what would be the easiest way to add an option at the top of the list above all the data from the MySQL table to say none also with a value of none?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a row with a 'sequence' of 0, named 'none'

```
Dim newRow = dt.NewRow()
newRow("sequence") = 0
newRow("name") = "none"
dt.Rows.Add(newRow)
```

Of course you will want to handle this row specially, and not insert it if you decide to write back to the database.

See "Inserting a New Record into an Untyped Dataset" in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034(v=vs.80).aspx for more info.

Comment: oh right i see ok - where would i insert this amongst my code?

Comment: After da.Fill, before setting the datasource on the control

Comment: O great thank you - how do we make this option display at the top and automatically selected?

Comment: You could do something like `dt.DefaultView.Sort = "sequence asc";` and then use the DefaultView instead of the raw table as the DataSource